# Use .prev() to go outside of table?

Tags: jquery

I have this function:

```
function ChangeColor(element) {
    $(element).prev("SPAN").css("background-color", "");
    if (element.value.length < 1) {
        $(element).prev("SPAN").css("background-color", "#FFBED1");
    }
}
```

And this HTML:

```
<span style="background-color: #FFBED1">
    Answer this question:<br>
</span>
<input name=Q1 onchange="ChangeColor(this);"><br><br>

<span style="background-color: #FFBED1">
    Answer this question also:
</span>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Question 2</td>
        <td><input name=Q2 onchange="ChangeColor(this);"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It doesn't change the background on the `span` before the question in the `table`. Is there a way to make this function work with both `input` elements?

I've tried adding:

```
   if($(element).prev("SPAN").get(0)==undefined) {$(element).parent().prev("SPAN").css("background-color","");}
```

but that doesn't seem to help or change anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `closest()` to find the `table` element, then `prev()` to get the sibling `span` from there. You would also need a little logic to cater for the cases where the `span` is a direct sibling of the `input` or when the `input` is in the `table`. Try this:

```
function ChangeColor(element) {
    var $span = $(element).prev('span');
    if (!$span.length)
        $span = $(element).closest('table').prev('span');

    $span.css("background-color", "");
    if (element.value.length < 1) {
        $span.css("background-color", "#FFBED1");
    }
}
```

Also note that it's much better practice to use unobtrusive JS to attach your event handlers and avoid the use of outdated `on*` event attributes. As you've tagged the question with jQuery, here's how to do that:

```
<span class="empty">
    Answer this question:<br />
</span>
<input name="Q1" class="question"><br /><br />

<span class="empty">
    Answer this question also:
</span>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Question 2</td>
        <td><input name="Q2" class="question"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$('.question').change(function() {
    var $q = $(this);
    var $span = $q.prev('span');
    if (!$span.length)
        $span = $q.closest('table').prev('span');

    $span.toggleClass('empty', !$q.val().length);
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/fLd8za5p/)

Note the use of a class over directly applying some CSS to the element which allows us to use the `toggleClass()` method with a boolean state flag to add/remove the class as required.

Comment: Thanks for all the detail! And I'll work on using unobtrusive JS. I'm new to jquery, so this really helps alot.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.prev` of the `<input>` element is the nothing as there's no element before it. You need to go up to the parent `<table>` which is a sibling of the span first.

```
$(element).closest('table').prev('span');
```